# Why two lambs are sacrificed for baby boy but only one for a baby girl for aqiqah

Tags: fiqh, sharia, women, men, aqeeqah

I understand the wisdom of islam in giving half inheritance to women and half penalty for the killing of women- because men are the sole breadwinners for the family. I also understand the wisdom behind women's testimony being half of that of men's. But I need to understand the wisdom of why only one lamb is sacrificed for the birth of a baby girl but two for a baby boy. By that time, the boy doesn't earn anything for his family